# How to display field collection fields in tabs on add another item button?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type which has a multivalued field collection field. 
In this field I have a set of field collection items.
In field collection I have put the fields in horizontal tabs.

But the problem is when I click on add another item button it adds those set fields in a new row not in another horizontal tab.

Is there any module which should add fields in new horizontal tab? Or any custom code hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I used [multiple value widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_value_widget) module. It does exactly the same.